# Fatal Signal 11 error when drawing on canvas

Tags: c#, android, canvas, xamarin.android

I am running into an issue where swiping cells in my recycler view results in the application throwing a signal 11 error.

After looking into this issue on google/stackoverflow i found out that some people seemed to be able to fix it by setting the layer of a view to software rendering rather than hardware accelerated rendering - unfortunately in my case that did not fix the issue for me, nor was i able to find any suggestions which were really different from fixing it like that.

I attempted to do fix this by setting the "container" with that method as well as the ItemView of the viewholder - neither one prevented the error.

Is someone able to tell me what's so special about my scenario that i can't get it to work?

The error happens with line 242 of LeftRightSwipeController.cs

The full reproduction sample is available on github at:
https://github.com/devsolvum/Signal-11-CanvasDraw

LeftRightSwipeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget.Helper;
using Android.Views;
using Math = Java.Lang.Math;
using Object = Java.Lang.Object;

namespace App1.Domain
{
    // https://medium.com/@fanfatal/android-swipe-menu-with-recyclerview-8f28a235ff28
    // https://github.com/FanFataL/swipe-controller-demo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/pl/fanfatal/swipecontrollerdemo/SwipeController.java

    public enum SwipeState
    {
        Default,
        LeftOpen,
        RightOpen
    }

    public class LeftRightSwipeController : ItemTouchHelper.Callback
    {
        private bool _swipeBack = false;

        private SwipeState _currentSwipeState = SwipeState.Default;

        private RectF _buttonInstance = null;

        public override int ConvertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection)
        {
            if (_swipeBack)
            {
                _swipeBack = _currentSwipeState != SwipeState.Default;
                return 0;
            }
            return base.ConvertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
        }

        public override void OnChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX,
            float dY, int actionState, bool isCurrentlyActive)
        {
            var measuredsize = GetMeasuredSize(GetContainerArea(dX), viewHolder);
            if (measuredsize.width <= 0 || measuredsize.height <= 0)
                return;

            var clippedX = dX >= 0 ? Math.Min(dX, measuredsize.width) : Math.Max(dX, -measuredsize.width);

            if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ActionStateSwipe)
            {
                if (_currentSwipeState != SwipeState.Default)
                {
                    if (_currentSwipeState == SwipeState.LeftOpen)
                        clippedX = Math.Max(clippedX, measuredsize.width);
                    if (_currentSwipeState == SwipeState.RightOpen)
                        clippedX = Math.Min(clippedX, -measuredsize.width);

                    base.OnChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, clippedX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                }
                else
                {
                    SetTouchListener(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                }
            }

            if (_currentSwipeState == SwipeState.Default)
            {
                base.OnChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, clippedX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }

            DrawButtons(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive, _currentSwipeState, false);
        }

        private (int width, int height) GetMeasuredSize(int containerArea, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder)
        {
            if (viewHolder is IViewHolderButtonContainer buttonContainer)
            {
                int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(viewHolder.ItemView.Width, MeasureSpecMode.AtMost);
                int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(viewHolder.ItemView.Height, MeasureSpecMode.AtMost);

                var container = buttonContainer.CreateButtonContainer(containerArea);
                container.Measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

                return (container.MeasuredWidth, container.MeasuredHeight);
            }

            return (0, 0);
        }

        private void SetItemsClickable(RecyclerView recyclerView, bool isClickable)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < recyclerView.ChildCount; ++i)
            {
                recyclerView.GetChildAt(i).Clickable = isClickable;
            }
        }

        private void SetTouchListener(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX,
            float dY, int actionState, bool isCurrentlyActive)
        {
            recyclerView.SetOnTouchListener(
                new TouchListenerDelegate(
                    (v, @event) =>
                    {
                        _swipeBack = @event.Action == MotionEventActions.Cancel || @event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up;
                        if (_swipeBack)
                        {
                            float containerWidth = GetMeasuredSize(GetContainerArea(dX), viewHolder).width;

                            if (dX <= -containerWidth)
                            {
                                _currentSwipeState = SwipeState.RightOpen;
                            }
                            else if (dX >= containerWidth)
                            {
                                _currentSwipeState = SwipeState.LeftOpen;
                            }

                            if (_currentSwipeState != SwipeState.Default)
                            {
                                DrawButtons(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive, _currentSwipeState, true);
                                SetTouchDownListener(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                                SetItemsClickable(recyclerView, false);
                            }
                        }

                        return false;
                    }));
        }

        private void SetTouchDownListener(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX,
            float dY, int actionState, bool isCurrentlyActive)
        {
            recyclerView.SetOnTouchListener(
                new TouchListenerDelegate(
                    (view, args) =>
                    {
                        if (args.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
                        {
                            SetTouchUpListener(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }));
        }

        private void SetTouchUpListener(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX,
            float dY, int actionState, bool isCurrentlyActive)
        {
            recyclerView.SetOnTouchListener(
                new TouchListenerDelegate(
                    (recyclerViewInDelegate, outerArgs) =>
                    {
                        if (outerArgs.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
                        {
                            recyclerView.SetOnTouchListener(
                                new TouchListenerDelegate(
                                    (innerView, innerArgs) => { return false; }));

                            SetItemsClickable(recyclerView, true);
                            _swipeBack = false;

                            //                          if (_buttonsActions != null && _buttonInstance != null &&
                            //                              _buttonInstance.Contains(outerArgs.GetX(), outerArgs.GetY()))
                            //                          {
                            //                              if (_currentSwipeState == SwipeState.LeftOpen)
                            //                              {
                            //                                  _buttonsActions.OnLeftClicked(viewHolder.AdapterPosition);
                            //                              }
                            //                              else if (_currentSwipeState == SwipeState.RightOpen)
                            //                              {
                            //                                  _buttonsActions.OnRightClicked(viewHolder.AdapterPosition);
                            //                              }
                            //                          }

                            _currentSwipeState = SwipeState.Default;


                            // folgende codezeile behebt einen darstellungsbug, wenn man eine schaltfläche klickt
                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                            base.OnChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, 0, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                        }

                        return false;
                    }));
        }


        private void DrawButtons(Canvas canvas, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX,
            float dY, int actionState, bool isCurrentlyActive, SwipeState swipeState, bool swipeEnd)
        {
            var validState = isCurrentlyActive || swipeState != SwipeState.Default;


            if (!validState)
                return;

            if (viewHolder is IViewHolderButtonContainer buttonContainer)
            {
                //              int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified);

                int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(viewHolder.ItemView.Width, MeasureSpecMode.AtMost);
                int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(viewHolder.ItemView.Height, MeasureSpecMode.AtMost);

                var containerArea = GetContainerArea(dX);
                var container = buttonContainer.CreateButtonContainer(containerArea);
                container.Measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

                var clippedWidth = GetClippedWidth(viewHolder.ItemView.Width, dX, container.MeasuredWidth);
                if (clippedWidth <= 0)
                    return;
                var clippedHeight = GetClippedHeight(viewHolder.ItemView.Height, dY, container.MeasuredHeight);
                if (clippedHeight <= 0)
                    return;

                var viewLeft = dX >= 0 ? viewHolder.ItemView.Left : viewHolder.ItemView.Right - clippedWidth;
                var viewTop = viewHolder.ItemView.Top;
                var viewRight = viewLeft + clippedWidth;
                var viewBottom = viewTop + clippedHeight;

                container.Layout(viewLeft, viewTop, viewRight, viewBottom);

                container.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Orange);

                //              var canvasX = dX >= 0 ? viewHolder.ItemView.Left : viewHolder.ItemView.Left + viewHolder.ItemView.Width;

                //                  var paint = new Paint();
                //                  paint.Color = Color.Aqua;
                //                  canvas.DrawRect(viewLeft, viewTop, viewRight, viewBottom, paint);

                // Translate the canvas so the view is drawn at the proper coordinates
                canvas.Save();
                canvas.Translate(viewLeft, viewHolder.ItemView.Top);

                if (swipeEnd)
                {
                    viewHolder.ItemView.Invalidate();
                    container.Invalidate();
                }

                //Draw the View and clear the translation
                container.Draw(canvas);
                canvas.Restore();
            }
        }

        private static int GetContainerArea(float dX)
        {
            return dX >= 0 ? 0 : 1;
        }

        private int GetClippedHeight(int viewHolderHeight, float dY, int measured)
        {
            return viewHolderHeight;
        }

        private int GetClippedWidth(int viewHolderWidth, float dX, int measured)
        {
            if (viewHolderWidth <= 0)
                return 0;

            return Math.Min(measured, (int) Math.Ceil(Math.Abs(dX)));
        }


        public override int GetMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder)
        {
            return MakeMovementFlags(0, ItemTouchHelper.Left | ItemTouchHelper.Right);
        }

        public override bool OnMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder target)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public override void OnSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction)
        {
        }

        private class TouchListenerDelegate : Object, View.IOnTouchListener
        {
            public void Dispose()
            {
                Callback = null;
            }

            public TouchListenerDelegate(Func<View, MotionEvent, bool> callback)
            {
                Callback = callback;
            }

            public Func<View, MotionEvent, bool> Callback { get; set; }

            public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
            {
                return Callback(v, e);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IViewHolderButtonContainer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Erstellt container für die Buttons
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="containerArea">0 = links, 1 = rechts</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        View CreateButtonContainer(int containerArea);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget.Helper;
using Android.Views;
using App1.Domain;

namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            var mainView = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Main, null, true) as LinearLayout;
            SetContentView(mainView);
            mainView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
            var recyclerView = new RecyclerView(this);
            var recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter();
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                recyclerAdapter.Items.Add($"Entry {i}.");
            }
            recyclerView.SetAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
            var linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            var swipeController = new LeftRightSwipeController();
            var ith = new ItemTouchHelper(swipeController);
            ith.AttachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
            recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Orange);
            mainView.AddView(recyclerView);
        }

        public class RecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
        {
            public List<string> Items { get; set; } = new List<string>();

            public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
            {
                var data = Items[position];
                var textView = holder.ItemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1);
                if (textView != null)
                {
                    textView.Text = data;
                }
            }

            public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
            {
                var inflater = Android.Views.LayoutInflater.FromContext(parent.Context);
                var view = inflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, parent, false);
                return new CustomViewHolder(view);
            }

            public override int ItemCount => Items.Count;
        }

        public class CustomViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder, IViewHolderButtonContainer
        {
            public CustomViewHolder(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
            {
            }

            public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
            {
            }

            private View _leftContainer;
            private View _rightContainer;

            public View CreateButtonContainer(int containerArea)
            {
                if (containerArea == 0)
                {
                    return _leftContainer ?? (_leftContainer = CreateContainer(containerArea));
                }
                else
                {
                    return _rightContainer ?? (_rightContainer = CreateContainer(containerArea));
                }
            }

            private string GetButtonText(int containerArea)
            {
                return $"Button area {containerArea}";
            }

            private View CreateContainer(int containerArea)
            {
                var textView = new TextView(Android.App.Application.Context);
                textView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Blue);
                textView.Text = GetButtonText(containerArea);
                return textView;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions to try and fix this are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the layer type on the recyclerview to software fixed the issue. Turns out i picked the wrong view to set it.